# LIKE do MySQL não encontra se buscar pelo nome inteiro

Tags: mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho um sistema de busca em MySQL + PHP, ele faz a busca assim:

```
$nome = "Treinamento Da Venda à Entrega (Teste)";
$sqlPost = "SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%'";
$resultPost = mysql_query($sqlPost);
$buscou = mysql_num_rows($resultPost);
echo $buscou;
```

No banco tenho o seguinte nome cadastrado:

```
Treinamento Da Venda à Entrega (Teste)
```

Se eu busco pela palavra **venda**, ele acha, por **entrega** ele acha, mas se busco por exatamente **Treinamento Da Venda à Entrega (Teste)** ele não acha, estou usando o LIKE errado?

O que percebi é que ele busca apenas por 1 palavra, se coloco mais de um ele não acha.

Comment: Passa o trecho completo do código

Comment: Oi, coloquei, achei meio irrelevante, pois a dúvida está mais na forma como o LIKE trabalha que no código em si.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei buscando por REGEXP:

```
$nome = "Treinamento Da Venda à Entrega (Teste)";
$nome2 = str_replace(" ", "|", $nome);
$nomeBusca = "SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE nome REGEXP '".$nome2."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

No parâmetro `$sqlPost = "SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%'";` ele vai tentar procurar na base palavras que contenham `nome` na palavra por isso nao retorna nenhum valor, pois `Treinamento Da Venda à Entrega (Teste)`nao possui `nome` em seu contexto, e o `"`nesse caso não é necessário. Uma recomendação é utilizar `Like '% alguma coisa';` como por exemplo `Like 'a%';` ele vai procurar valores que comecem com a letra A ou `Like '%a';` nesse caso ele procura valores que terminem com a letra A. Mais exemplos de como utilizar o `Like`, pode encontrar nesse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Em resumo, o seu `Like` para encontrar o valor todo, no caso `Treinamento Da Venda à Entrega (Teste)`, você deve passar o seguinte parâmetro `Like '"Treinamento Da Venda à Entrega (Teste)"'`

Comment: Não.... o MySQL reconhece a variável dessa forma. E se buscar por isso: Like '"Treinamento Da Venda à Entrega (Teste)"' ele não retorna

Answer (score 0):

Busque usando o coringa ou pelo nome inteiro:

```
$sqlPost = "SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE nome LIKE '%$nome%' OR nome = '$nome'";
```

Ou então se quiser uma busca mais abrangente por sobrenomes use:

```
SELECT id FROM tabela 
    WHERE nome LIKE REPLACE('$nome',' ','%') 
       OR nome LIKE '%$nome%'
```

Comment: É uma opção, mas se buscar por metade do nome, ja da erro.

Comment: Fiz uma atualização com uma query mais abrangente